# Enabling English UK spell check in a UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, spell-checking, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to enable spell check in my UWP application (Windows 10) using English UK spelling.

So far the only way I have managed to get spell check to work at all is by installing the English (US) language pack onto my device, but I would like to have UK spelling not US. I also noticed that the Spelling settings (as seen in [this article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-spell-checker-windows-10)) only show up under Typing when the US language pack is installed. There is no Spelling section even when I have English (UK) installed.

Other notes: the device I am using is a Surface 3 tablet and my default language pack is English (New Zealand).

How can I get the spell check working in UWP for English (UK)?

Comment: It seems we should be able to set the English(United Kingdom)  as the default language in Settings.

Comment: This is correct - and we also needed the optional feature English (GB) Typing. These had been locked down on the tablet we were using but have got this installed now. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to add this as an answer I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, some users might use an Input Method Editor (IME) to enter another language into your app, and that language might be supported. For example, when building a Japanese language app, even though the spell checking engine might not currently recognize that language, don't turn spell checking off. The user may switch to an English IME and type English into the app; if spell checking is enabled, the English will get spell checked.

For more info, please refer the [Guidelines for spell checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/text-controls#guidelines-for-spell-checking).

When we set the English(United Kingdom) as the default language in Settings, it will spell check English(GB) typing. When we switch input method to Englich(United States), it can also spell check English(US) typing.

We can open the Manage optional features in Apps & features in Settings. It lists Optional features, we can see English (GB) typing: Spelling, text prediction, and document searching for English(GB).